# See what HTTP calls were made

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I know I can use ngMockE2E/ngMock module to mock HTTP calls and have them respond with a custom output. But is there a way how to test if a HTTP specific request were made? Ideally with possibility to add expectations such as what POST parameters or headers were sent?

Normally I would just check UI for changes, but there are some requests (such as logging) that do not affect UI in any way.

Comment: check $httpBackend documentation

Comment: That is also covered by ngMock.

Comment: @epitka But I cannot access $httpBackend inside of my tests (it statements) as it runs in a different scope than the actual tests.

Answer (score 0):

The more basic solution for this would be to use the Debug Tools from your browser. Google Chrome Dev Tools has a great Network Panel logging every request, including the header and the response. You should look at its [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network) for more information.

A cleaner way would be to use the `$httpBackend` with its `expect` method. Look at the [Angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) for examples.

Comment: Can't use Chrome Dev Tools with protractor. It should work in protractor debug mode, but according GitHub issues it's bugged since v0.18.

Comment: ngMockE2E `$httpBackend` has no `expect` method :(